# WPF Shader Effect - antialiasing not showing

Tags: wpf, shader, antialiasing

I am running to a problem where I have a WPF shader effect (modified from Rene Schulte) to simulate Dot Matrix Display (DMD). Everything works great, but all dots are aliased.

See attached image. 
[image]

I tried many features within WPF, to bring antialiasing, nothing to do.

in constructor (image within a textbox);

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(MarqueeTB, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(MarqueeTB, EdgeMode.Unspecified);
RenderOptions.SetClearTypeHint(MarqueeTB, ClearTypeHint.Enabled);
```

I don't think it is my graphic card or Windows config. I did some testing on two PCs, same results; Windows 8.1 and Windows 7.

I have no clue how to proceed. Any help or advises would be welcome.

Thanks in advance, regards, 
Shader code:

```
//   Project:           Shaders
//
//   Description:       Mosaic Shader for Coding4Fun.
//
//   Changed by:        $Author$
//   Changed on:        $Date$
//   Changed in:        $Revision$
//   Project:           $URL$
//   Id:                $Id$
//
//
//   Copyright (c) 2010 Rene Schulte
//

/// <description>Mosaic Shader for Coding4Fun.</description>

/// <summary>The number pixel blocks.</summary>
/// <type>Single</type>
/// <minValue>2</minValue>
/// <maxValue>500</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>50</defaultValue>
float BlockCount : register(C0);

/// <summary>The rounding of a pixel block.</summary>
/// <type>Single</type>
/// <minValue>0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.45</defaultValue>
float Max : register(C2);

/// <summary>The aspect ratio of the image.</summary>
/// <type>Single</type>
/// <minValue>0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>10</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
float AspectRatio : register(C3);

// Sampler
sampler2D input : register(S0);

// Static computed vars for optimization
static float2 BlockCount2 = float2(BlockCount, BlockCount  / AspectRatio);
static float2 BlockSize2 = 1.0f / BlockCount2; 

// Shader
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
     // Calculate block center
     float2 blockPos = floor(uv * BlockCount2);
     float2 blockCenter = blockPos * BlockSize2 + BlockSize2 * 0.5;

     // Scale coordinates back to original ratio for rounding
     float2 uvScaled = float2(uv.x * AspectRatio, uv.y);
     float2 blockCenterScaled = float2(blockCenter.x * AspectRatio, blockCenter.y);

     // Round the block by testing the distance of the pixel coordinate to the center
     float dist = length(uvScaled - blockCenterScaled) * BlockCount2;
     if(dist < 0 || dist > Max)
     {
         return 1;
     }

     // Sample color at the calculated coordinate
     return tex2D(input, blockCenter);
}
```

Comment: I'd guess you have to multiply the colour values with alpha, but it's been a while.

Comment: Ok, I have it working. I am not sure if this is 'the' way to do it, but it worked. Here is the solution that worked for me: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34582/how-do-i-use-screen-space-derivatives-to-antialias-a-parametric-shape-in-a-pixel

Comment: Antialiasing only applies to vectors like text and shapes in WPF. If you want antialiasing, I would suggest precomputing that in your dot texture.

(not so) Fun fact: setting a shader effect directly on a shape will cause antialiasing to not be applied. To get around this, you need to apply the shader effect on the enclosing WPF element (like a blank border) - that's how I ended up here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the *best* solution, but it works. See the `antialiasedCircle` part of [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/34598) answer.

```
//  Project:           Dot Matrix Display (DMD) Shader
//  Inspired from From Mosaic shader Copyright (c) 2010 Rene Schulte


/// <summary>The number pixel blocks.</summary>
/// <type>Single</type>
/// <minValue>2</minValue>
/// <maxValue>500</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>34</defaultValue>


float BlockCount : register(C0);

/// <summary>The rounding of a pixel block.</summary>
/// <type>Single</type>
/// <minValue>0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.45</defaultValue>
float Max : register(C2);

/// <summary>The aspect ratio of the image.</summary>
/// <type>Single</type>
/// <minValue>0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>10</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.55</defaultValue>
float AspectRatio : register(C3);

/// <summary>The monochrome color used to tint the input.</summary>
/// <defaultValue>Yellow</defaultValue>
float4 FilterColor : register(C1);

/// <summary>monochrome.</summary>
/// <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
float IsMonochrome : register(C4);

// Sampler
sampler2D input : register(S0);

// Static computed vars for optimization
static float2 BlockCount2 = float2(BlockCount, BlockCount  / AspectRatio);
static float2 BlockSize2 = 1.0f / BlockCount2; 

float4 setMonochrome(float4 color) : COLOR
{
   float4 monochrome= color;
   if(((int)IsMonochrome) == 1)
   {
      float3 rgb = color.rgb;
      float3 luminance = dot(rgb, float3(0.30, 0.59, 0.11));
     monochrome= float4(luminance * FilterColor.rgb, color.a);
   }
    return monochrome;
}

float4 SetDMD(float2 uv : TEXCOORD, sampler2D samp) : COLOR
{
     // Calculate block center
     float2 blockPos = floor(uv * BlockCount2);
     float2 blockCenter = blockPos * BlockSize2 + BlockSize2 * 0.5;
     
     // Scale coordinates back to original ratio for rounding
     float2 uvScaled = float2(uv.x * AspectRatio, uv.y);
     float2 blockCenterScaled = float2(blockCenter.x * AspectRatio, blockCenter.y);
         
     // Round the block by testing the distance of the pixel coordinate to the center
     float dist = length(uvScaled - blockCenterScaled) * BlockCount2;
     
      float4 insideColor= tex2D(samp, blockCenter);
       
     float4 outsideColor = insideColor; 
         outsideColor.r = 0; 
         outsideColor.g = 0; 
         outsideColor.b = 0; 
         outsideColor.a = 1; 
         
      float distFromEdge = Max - dist;  // positive when inside the circle
     float thresholdWidth = .22;  // a constant you'd tune to get the right level of softness
     float antialiasedCircle = saturate((distFromEdge / thresholdWidth) + 0.5);
     
     return lerp(outsideColor, insideColor, antialiasedCircle);
}

// Shader
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
     float4 DMD= SetDMD(uv, input);
     DMD = setMonochrome(DMD);
       
     return DMD;
}
```

Here is an image of the successful solution:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it layout rounding? Try `MarqueeTB.UseLayoutRounding = false;`

Comment: No "MarqueeTB.UseLayoutRounding = false" doesn't bring help after trying it. But thanks. On other hand, I did some more tests by drawing a simple shape (circle) in a canvas. The circle has antialiasing until I apply the shader effect to it.