# Render DMD in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render

I want to render a custom display from an emulation. Think like a dot matrix display from pinball machines.

How would i effectively go about this? (Think about actually writing to a texture that size will probably run way too slow)

There has to be a good way to get this to render, but i have trouble finding a way that actually performs properly as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to do this but without further details (DMD screen resolution, number of colors, animated or not, etc) it's not easy to help. Here are a bunch of options popped into my mind, hope the one you are looking for is somewhere here :)
**1)** There was a similar question, you can find it along with the answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452349/wpf-shader-effect-antialiasing-not-showing)

**2)** If you want to display text only, there's a wide range of sites offering DMD fonts for free, e.g. [**here**](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital+dot-matrix-fonts.html)
**3)** You can also edit/extend the font set you download and display 'special characters' as graphics, or just use the standard [ASCII table](http://courseweb.unt.edu/gjones/fall2010/ltec3530/images/ascii2.gif) for the purpose if that's enough for your needs. e.g. ▓ █ ╔ ═ ╗ and similar "drawing characters"
You can find inspiration and ASCII art (*including animated ones*) e.g. [**here**](http://www.asciimator.net/)
**4)** Might be slow (again, "depends") but you can go for bitmap and `.SetPixels` with a `Texture2D` and `DrawTexture`

**5)** A bit "hacky", but you can save your anim phases into either bitmap data/array (readonly/constant variables for example, or read from disc in a managed way, or draw with the help of a free asset from the store, like [this one here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18810), etc) and do `Graphics.DrawTexture`

**6)** If the thing you want to display is 100% static (i.e. it's not actual data like score, but "hardcoded" animations like "TILT" text or such), you can create a Sprite Animation

**7)** You can mix the above and e.g. go for a font (#2) to display dynamic data on a canvas, and play the static animation around it making it look like the whole thing is dynamic
Hm. That's all right off the top of my head :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Most of these are not applicable. I am trying to do the DMD, but live from emulation, and 1 dot would be 1 pixel (close enough). So i don't know shaders, but i think setpixels would be too slow. Can Graphics.DrawTexture not use runtime generated buffers?